# Adding type annotations to JSX, mistakes the type for a JSX tag

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, flowtype

I'm trying to add this style of flowtype annotation to my component (from [React typeReference](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-element))

```
class Foo extends React.Component<{}> {}
function Bar(props: {}) {}

(<Foo />: React.Element<typeof Foo>); // OK
(<Bar />: React.Element<typeof Bar>); // OK
(<Foo />: React.Element<typeof Bar>); // Error: Foo is not Bar
```

My attempt:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import type { Node, Element } from 'react'

class AlertModalComponent extends Component<iAlertModal, State> {
  render(): Node {
    return (
      <View style={alertModalStyle.container}>
        (<PresentationalModal
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
          isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
          title={this.props.title}
          message={this.props.message}
          updateAlertModalHeight={this.props.updateAlertModalHeight}
          viewHeight={this.props.viewHeight}
          hasYesNo={this.props.hasYesNo}
          yesClicked={this.props.yesClicked}
          updateAlertModalIsOpen={this.props.updateAlertModalIsOpen}
        />: Element<typeof PresentationalModal>)
      </View>
    )
  }
}

// $FlowFixMe
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AlertModalComponent)

AlertModalComponent.contextTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
}

const PresentationalModal: Function = ({
  isOpen,
  title,...
}: AlertModal) => {
  console.log('presentational modal yes no')
  return (
    <Modal style={alertModalStyle.modal} isVisible={isOpen}>
...
```

error:

> Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for `<typeof>`

It thinks `<typeof>` is a jsx tag. What is the solution to this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a flow type annotation in the middle of jsx. You would need to pull it outside like this

```
render(): Node {
  const presentationalModel: Element<typeof PresentationalModal> = (
    <PresentationalModal
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
      isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
      title={this.props.title}
      message={this.props.message}
      updateAlertModalHeight={this.props.updateAlertModalHeight}
      viewHeight={this.props.viewHeight}
      hasYesNo={this.props.hasYesNo}
      yesClicked={this.props.yesClicked}
      updateAlertModalIsOpen={this.props.updateAlertModalIsOpen}
    />
  )
  return (
    <View style={alertModalStyle.container}>
      {presentationalModal}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Is there a reason you want to explicitly type this though? Adding this type definition wouldn't be making your code any safer; flow already knows that `<PresentationModal ... />` is a typeof PresentationModal. It seems like it's adding clutter.

Comment: Hmm okay fair enough. Isn't the type annotation getting added in the JSX in my top example from the react typereference though?

Comment: The difference is that the top example, it's the entire jsx value that is being typed, whereas the one that doesn't work, it's in the middle of a jsx expression.